# Bonjour/ZeroConf Implementation for Android(HoneyComb)

Tags: android, bonjour

I am trying to implement bonjour/zero conf on my android app for Android tablet using Honeycomb. I am using jmDns library for searching the all the available devices. I need a list of android devices connected to wifi.

Basically, i am adding them in a list so that i can display a list of all available devices. Now when I am running this code on emulator, nothing is added to my list( but there are 5-6 devices in the list)

Can anyone please help in providing some code snippet. I am not sure if bonjour/zero conf is supported by Honeycomb or its a problem with my emulator. Thanx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Emulator has a private virtual network between it and host machine. Zeroconf uses broadcast to query for devices and this query only propagates on this virtual network.

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/emulator.html#emulatornetworking

Comment: Additionally, not all Android devices can broadcast -- something I discovered when doing homework for my TiVo Music Server.  Apparently, some devices have this disabled by the manufacturer at the driver level. I ended up implementing both Bonjour/Rendezvous and the TiVo beacon for discovery.